# javascript search function read '*' and '.' as the same

Tags: javascript, match

I am having trouble with my javascript code because match function read '*' and '.' as the same.

Here is the code:

```
var value = "sample*com";
var rules = new Array(".com ",".net",".org",".us",".ca",".com");
var found = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
   var filter = new RegExp('\\b' + rules[i] + '\\b', 'gi');
   if(value.match(filter)) {
      found++;
      console.log("found .com");
   } 
}
```

The problem is, why the script detect * as '.'? Because the console says that "found .com" even that the value  = "sample*com" .

Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: I tested `"sample*com".indexOf(".")` and `-1` was returned...

Comment: It's interpreting it as a regular expression, where "." matches any character

Comment: http://scriptular.com/ may help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape `.` in `.com` as `\.com`. Otherwise the dot matches *any* character. So in your rules array, you will have to double escape it as `\\.com`.

Comment: so my rules declaration will looks like this?var rules = new Array("\.com ","\.net","\.org","\.us","\.ca","\.com");